# Regular expression to get everything between <a and </a> containing my url

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have to create a test application on JMeter where i need to get only that anchor tag and all its content which has my url name.

```
<a href='http://www.mysite.com/' title='Free Stuff' target='_NEW'>Free Stuff</a>
```

or any other variant is returned. Only prerequisite is that it should start with < a , have mysite.com in between and < / a > at the end.
I have endlessly tried to do this, even searched this forum but to no avail.
Help needed desperately.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572

Comment: @Bergi Since <a> tags are rarely nested, that answer really doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the parts you require and fill the remainder of the pattern with "give me anything".

```
<a[^>]*mysite\.com.+?<\/a>
```

### [demo](http://rubular.com/r/hCRD65wtet)

Comment: This actually does not stop at the first occurrence of </ a> but goes on till it finds </ a>

Comment: Thanks.  I just threw a `?` in there, which should fix it.  In most implementations, that would only matter if they were on the same line, but good catch.